# How I can differentiate between loops come inside the main function and loops come in another method outside the main function?

Tags: java, function, loops, for-loop, antlr4

I am programming with java targeting c++ language using this grammar file [CPP14](https://gofile.io/d/DatdWE).

My main objective is to locate loops in the input file and do some analysis on statements inside them and I partially reach this objective by visiting loops (for, while and do-while) in visitor, I save the string I get from getText in ArrayList in another class to do the analysis on it.

```
public Object visitClassicForStatement(GrammarParser.ClassicForStatementContext ctx) {
  String Str1 = ctx.statement().compoundstatement().statementseq().statement().getText();
  check.checlLoops(Str1);
  if (check.flag()) {
    String message = "true";
    rewriter.insertBefore(ctx.start, message);
  }
```

but in the process to make my tool getting more mature I am facing a problem now, and that problem happening, because if I have functions in the input file like in the following example:

```
void add(int a[]);
int main()
{
    int a[11] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
    add(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void add(int a[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
    }
}
```

my tool will enter on the functions and do the analysis on statements inside the loop and write above the loop which is good **but** after this analysis, I want to save the statements under the loop inside functions in another ArrayList like what I did with the getText() in the beginning to do further analysis, because all the statements under the loop will come in the Str1 but I can't enter to function body and get the text the same way I did with loops in the previous code snippet.

How can I get the statements inside loops that occur inside functions other than the main function and save them in a separate ArrayList than the previous ArrayList, and how I can save the name of any function identifier, and function calls in the code other than the main function in two ArrayLists one for the identifiers and other for function calls.

here is the parse tree of the example that I mentioned above [parse tree](https://gofile.io/d/iG22HL)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If correctly understand then you use a visitor to get the content of loops in your parse tree, but you cannot tell apart different loops (because they are all handled in the same visitor method). Is that correct?

If so then use the parse tree path to determine where you are when executing the visitor. The given context has a parent member, which in turn also has a parent member. So you can create an invocation chain for each call of your visitor method. Use that to find the position in the input (top level, some function, nested or anonymous functions etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Mike, yes it is correct what you understand from my question. and I am sorry for my English language. I have a problem of dealing with the parse tree especially when it comes to parents and children, and as you can see I use the parse tree to take the text directly without handling parents or children, can you please give me some examples that handle the same issue because I tried to understand the concept of dealing with parents and children but can't find good implementation to illustrate the concept to me, thank you in advance.

Comment: after looking in the tree, if the loops came inside the main function the way to reach to it from the root of the tree is by going through this way: declaration seq -> declaration -> function definition -> function body -> compound statement -> statement seq -> statement seq -> statement - > then the loop will be hear. and if the loop come outside the main function almost will follow the same previous path  that loop inside the main method, and it gets harder if I have more than one method outside the main